# Threaded Popen crashing on segmentation fault in 'bash'

Tags: python, multithreading, bash, popen

I've threaded Popen bash to run command line tools. bash generates a segfault or aborts the executing command.

```
def FunctionToThread(args):

    su2 = Popen('bash', shell = True, stdin = PIPE, stdout=fp, env = os.environ)
    for i in commands:
        su2.stdin.write(i)
    su2.stdin.close()
    su2.wait()
    fp.close()
```

The function FunctionToThread is threaded using using the threading module. As mentioned above, the thread terminates when a segfault is encountered in bash.

I want to either capture this segfault in a try/except type of control and most importantly prevent my thread from terminating.

How do I achieve this?

```
"""SNIPPET"""
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import threading
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os

start =0
numcores =  cpu_count()
global RESULTS, LOCK
LOCK = threading.Lock()
RESULTS = []

def ParallelRun(commands, RESULTS, LOCK):

    for i in range(0, 100):
        LOCK.acquire()
        RESULTS.append('ParallelRUn')
        LOCK.release()

    su2 = Popen('bash', shell = True, stdin = PIPE, stdout=PIPE, env = os.environ)
    for i in commands:
        su2.stdin.write(i)
    su2.stdin.close()
    err =su2.wait()


for i in range(0, numcores):
    commands = ['Enter commands which cause Segmentation Faults']
    t = threading.Thread(target=ParallelRun, args=(commands, RESULTS, LOCK))
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()


print len(RESULTS), RESULTS
```

To replicate my problem, in the **commands** list enter commands which generate segfaults.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible snippet which I can execute via copy+paste?

Comment: @guettli: I have added a snippet. In the commands list, a set of commands which generate Segmentation faults can be added.

Comment: pds you had a variable `fp` in the last snippet that was used as `stdout` and now you're using `PIPE`.  What prompted this change?

Comment: @tijko, fp was a file buffer. I was feeding the output to a file. I changed that in the snippet.

Comment: Thats what I thought just wanted to be sure.  What version of `python` are you running this on?

Comment: Hey @tijko & @guettli; The issue is resolved. It turns out that I had a return statement embedded in the if else loop which terminated the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is resolved. It turns out that I had a ***return*** statement in if/else blocks of the program which terminated my thread.